# In Wix, how can I avoid hardcoding a file source for a file that already exists in the installation directory?

Tags: wix, wix3, dynamics-gp

In my .wxs file, I have the following file declaration. This file already exists in the installation directory. It is not being copied from the source directory. I need to update it using util:XmlConfig during the install. The XmlConfig part is working.

```
<File Id="AppConfig" Name="Dynamics.exe.config" Source="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics\GP2010\Dynamics.exe.config" />
```

The problem is I can't assume the file is always going to exist in that same location. I'd really like to simply reference it like so:

```
<File Id="AppConfig" Name="[#INSTALLDIR]\Dynamics.exe.config" />
```

However, that fails with the following message:

```
> light.exe ....
The system cannot find the file 'SourceDir\....\[#INSTALLDIR]\Dynamics.exe.config'
```

How can I say "the file already exists in the installation directory, use that file during the installation, and do not validate for it now"?

Answer (score 0):

Directories are available with bracket notation as though they were regular properties. If you don't need to install the Dynamics.exe.config but just access it with `XmlConfig` elements, you can simply reference that directory and don't need to bother with the `File` element:

```
<Component Id="Dynamics.exe.config" KeyPath="yes" Guid="*">
  <util:XmlConfig Id="Dynamics.exe.config.XmlConfig1"
                  On="install"
                  Action="..."
                  File="[INSTALLDIR]\Dynamics.exe.config"
                  ...
                  />
  <util:XmlConfig Id="Dynamics.exe.config.XmlConfig2"
                  On="install"
                  Action="..."
                  File="[INSTALLDIR]\Dynamics.exe.config"
                  ...
                  />
</Component>
```